# Property 'x' is missing in type 'y' but required in type 'z'

Tags: typescript

I've got an object, which I'm calling a `ConstructorCollection` - it's an object of constructors for services, but could also be a tuple with a `Constructor` and any number of strings that are the keys of other services.

Here's a simple example:

```
interface Todos {
  add(text: string): void;
}

interface State {
  todos: string[];
}

export interface Services {
  state: State;
  todos: Todos;
}

const services: ConstructorCollection<Services> = {
  state: createState,
  todos: [createTodos, 'state'],
};

function createState(): State {
  return {} as unknown as State;
}

function createTodos(state: State): Todos {
  return {} as unknown as Todos;
}
```

And `ConstructorCollection` is defined like this:

```
export type Constructor<T, U> = (...args: U[]) => T;

export type ConstructorTuple<T, U> = [Constructor<T, T>, ...U[]];

export type ConstructorCollection<T, U extends keyof T = keyof T> = Record<
  U,
  Constructor<T[U], T[keyof T]> | ConstructorTuple<T[U], keyof T>
>;
```

With the error:

```
Type '(state: State) => Todos' is not assignable to type 'Constructor<Todos | State, Todos | State>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'Todos | State' is not assignable to type 'State'.
      Property 'todos' is missing in type 'Todos' but required in type 'State'.(2322)
```

So, why does TS think that `todos` should be in `Todos`? How can I get it to differentiate?

TS Playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2BnGUCuAxjNADwAqANHAKoB8cAvHABQB0HAhlAObYBctANoBdAJRMG5ANwAoWaEiwEyVBhx4iJKOXxgANsArV6TOEPW4CxMlTjk61DmxqiRcheGjwkKdFistaAx9Q2IASyxjWjhQGGBMABNsOABrYEQIADN7M3TMnIczACVgQmhE0lk4Wkpq-w1rbQohGhFqciF87PsRBgAfBsCbHT1DFrbqbsK6WToPcMx4qCzOQlRyCESIFIBves5ExJZ4kBhBK0WeMUEANwhwxLkAX3lF5dX1uABlGE54uD7GokbYCOCXTA8UQveSKbxwd7AFZrVDfJG3cLrPb1XD-YCCX54uTArY7QSbUEw2TlDTg9GY4BgyyaEYhMIwSKYUhoqAYrEMZhA8F-eKCQhQYB4wnxOok0GCITiyXxCk7agAclx8XV7Vkzw8WXwmAiWDgSqlIuALBuP0tgPqEpg+CgmEBzzgnBSRtSmAgAHdXZ7bUS9fJDcaOabzSrSdgWFr8cH4jbVdiao7na7du6g97fQGPSlUy8gA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main issue reason was found and this is how it can be fixed:

```
function createTodos(state: State | Todos): Todos {
  return {} as unknown as Todos;
}
```

not sure if that is ok with what you have in mind for the interface. To dig deeper into this API design you can open another ticket as commented on the spotted issue.

This is what the interface is telling you to describe, it makes clear my previous point

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is because of `strictFunctionTypes` tsconfig flag. If you set that off you will see it works.

this is because you are trying to make a function that is:

`(argument: A) => B`

equal to

`(argument: A) => B | (argument:A) => B;`

when using that strict function typing that's just not allowed since they are not the same function type.

Comment: That's a shame, because I'd like this to be public eventually and I wouldn't want to impose config on consumers. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: you will have to think the API is some other way probably with that in mind. If you want to expose that in detail maybe you can open a new stack overflow issue and mark this one as resolved? since it is clear now why the Typescript compiler fails. stack overflow questions shouldn't be evolving otherwise they are never ending

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's technically correct. But I would prefer rather than an answer that identifies the issue, one that solves the problem. The solution was in fact to add a second parameter to the `ConstructorCollection` type that would enable TS to identify the dependencies of each service constructor.